# Android View Animation problems: start animation upon event

Tags: android, animation, view

I have several `ImageViews` each with an indefinitely throbbing `ScaleAnimation` and three attempts that don't make sense to me.

- If I set the animation immediately after inflating the animation the animation runs perfectly.  This also tells me my helper function to create the animation (used in all three cases) is working fine.
- If I set the animation immediately, but with a start time of `Long.MAX`, and later call `icon.getAnimation().start()`, that animation starts but the speed is faster than it should be and the scale is not what I set.  No matter what I set the animation scale and duration parameters to, it always looks the same, unlike the previous case.
- If I call `icon.startAnimation(..)` with a new `Animation` object, I get no animation.  Digging into Android source, `startAnimation(..)` calls `invalidate()`, unlike `setAnimation(..)`.  If I call `icon.getAnimation().start()` followed by `icon.invalidate()` I get the same (lack of) behavior.  This hints to me that the invalidate somehow breaks the animation.

So, given all of the above, is this symptomatic of a mistake I might have made?  Is there something I didn't describe that I should be doing?

Finally, I've tried this with both a scale pivot specified both relatively and aboslutely, thinking there might be a bug in event order with respect to `View.invalidate()` and `Animation.reset()`.

Comment: Errr... Now it works, still following case #2 above.  Wasn't trying to fix it, so I'm not sure what the critical change was.

Comment: Correction:  It works intermitently, even in the same session.  However after the trigger event, either all the animations start, or they don't.  I'll investigate my event handling.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are having problems with animation. Working with animation on anything before Honeycomb is a real pain.

I recommend downloading the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library and using it as imports, that way you can use the Honeycomb animation API on all versions of android (even up to 1.0).